# Samsung Galaxy S5 upgraded Chrome version from 55 to 73. adb logcat not tracking network calls

Tags: networking, logging

I am developing automation test suite for monitoring Chrome browsers network calls on Android mobile device. My code was working fine with Chrome v72.

After upgrading Chrome version to 73. My code is not working. In debugging I realized that adb logcat is tracking browser network calls.

**Output with Chrome v55** for `adb -d logcat|grep "timesofindia"`:

```
03-30 16:27:48.586 16802 16802 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(199)] "city for the weather data..Ahmedabad", source: https://m.timesofindia.com/cityweather_js_v2.cms?v=2406 (199)
```

**Output with Chrome v73** for `adb -d logcat|grep "timesofindia"`:

*Nothing*

Do I have to change some configurations for fixing this issue? Please help me.

Comment: What does your code do? What chrome APIs does it use? Can you produce a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: My selenium appium webdriver code does following - read all details from console log: driver.manage().logs().get("logcat").getAll(); Capture details of request and responses of all network calls